# grep launches background processes

Tags: bash, background, grep

I have an input file that contains several path, including one referring to a initial solution. Corresponding line is the following:

```
initial_solution_file = ../../INIT/foo
```

What I would like to do is having an alias that would display this path so that I would type "init" and the shell would return " the initial solution is: ../../INIT/foo"

What I have tried is:

```
grep initial_solution_file input_file | awk '{print $3}' | echo "the initial solution is:" `xargs echo`
```

It provides the desired output, but I additionaly get something like:
    [6] 48201 48202

What is this and how to prevent it from happening ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to add `command` in front of `grep`. Like `command grep initial_solution_file input_file ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo "the initial solution is: $(awk '/initial_solution_file/{print $3}' input_file)"
the initial solution is: ../../INIT/foo
```

There is no need of pipes , you can do command substitution by using `$(....)` construct. Also, `grep` and `awk` can be done by `awk` alone.

Comment: Thanks it indeed works in bash =) 
However it returns "Illegal variable name." in tcsh. Any way to do it in tcsh ??

Comment: I juste copied it into a bash script which I execute from tcsh.
It's probably the uncleanest way to do it but it works.